# ASP.NET Core 3: How to reference 3.0.0 assemblies in custom libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-3.0

I see that applications that reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework (AKA ASP.NET Core 3.0) uses types from the assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0,`

[image]

But I can't find a NuGet package with same version `3.0.0`. How should I reference packages now? E.g. if I want to override `ControlBase`, how should I reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.0.0.0` assembly if there are [no such package versions on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/)?

After adding the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have another kind of waning:

[image]

Which gives the error:

> `NETSDK1073`: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized    Routines.AspNetCore C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   263

Unloading and reloading the application doesn't help.

The same problem occurs in an empty new project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Compilation

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ClassLibrary1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 1>C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(263,5):
> error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'
> was not recognized 1>Done building project "ClassLibrary1.csproj" --
> FAILED.
> ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add a `FrameworkReference` to your csproj

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

See [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) for more details

Comment: Thank you... Why I can't reference the only one assembly? I would like to understand the architects motivation....

Comment: And it doesn't work at least in my case. `TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` checked, no other libs. Even in new empty C# library (`netstandard2.1` of course).

Comment: It might be due to asp.net core 3 requiring .net core 3, and not `netstandard`. When I change my target framework to `netcoreapp3.0`, and add the `FrameworkReference`, it all works.

Comment: they wrote in `netstadard2.1` subset (what can be platform dependent in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions` ?) and then publish it exclusively `netcoreapp3.0` .. there are not limits for MS architects willfulness.