# Resolution of Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers assembly version 2.2.0 versus 6.0.0 depends on seemingly unrelated package references

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly, .net-standard, assembly-resolution

While trying to use HeaderNames.XFrameOptions, I found that it works in one of my projects and fails in another. Both are targeting .NET 6.

In my app, I need to work with the X-Frame-Options HTTP header. When possible, for maintainability reasons, I try to evade specifying constants for such standard strings myself, relying on standard constants instead. For this header's name, there is [HeaderNames.XFrameOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.headers.headernames.xframeoptions), available since ASP.NET Core 3.0.

By navigating to the class's implementation in VS, I found that the project where it works uses version 6.0.0.0 (.NET 6, x64) of the Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers assembly:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\6.0.12\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll

The project where it does not work uses version 2.2.0.0 (.NET Standard 2.0, MSIL) of the assembly:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll

The working project is the main project of my console app and the broken project is a library in the same solution, directly referenced by the console app.

When I looked into the broken project's obj\project.assets.json, I found that Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers is really used in version 2.2.0 and it is [referenced by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/2.2.0#dependencies-body-tab), which is also used in the broken project.

I used that info to reproduce the failure:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.404 --roll-forward disable
dotnet new console -f net6.0
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions --version 2.2.0
echo "Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.XFrameOptions);" > Program.cs
dotnet run
```

> C:\Repos\playground\Program.cs(1,58): error CS0117: 'HeaderNames' does not contain a definition for 'XFrameOptions' [C:\Repos\playground\playground.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

I tried adding all the packages referenced by the working project to the repro project and it fixed it! By elimination and following the dependencies of the last remaining project, I found that the fix can be achieved by adding just a single package ([AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client/6.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client/6.0.5#dependencies-body-tab)):

```
dotnet add package AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client --version 6.0.5
dotnet run
```

> X-Frame-Options

I see that AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client references the Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers assembly version 6.0.0.0, but directly, as an assembly, not as a NuGet package. Sadly, the latest packaged version is 2.2.0.0.

**How can I make HeaderNames.XFrameOptions work in both my projects at the same time?** Is installing an irrelevant package like AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client the only solution? And is there a more straightforward way to diagnose such assembly resolution issues?

Comment: By the way, I have read the [NuGet docs on dependency resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution).

Comment: Just add this package can fix this issue? But I don't find any relationship between this package and your issue.

Comment: @XinranShen, AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client references a newer version of the Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers assembly that I need. It fixes assembly resolution by that -- the new version is found. I would reference the new version of Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers package (using NuGet's rule ["direct dependency wins"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#direct-dependency-wins)), but sadly, there is no new version of the package. The new version of the assembly is not packaged. I can only reference another package using it and use the "cousin dependencies" rule.

Comment: If you do not believe, try. :-) The repro steps are really simple. You can omit the `dotnet new globaljson` step if you want to try it over a different SDK version. I believe it will be the same everywere in .NET Core. I just wanted to include the info on my specific environment.

Comment: Looks like this tackles exactly the same problem: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28630 I will need to read more on what a FrameworkReference is and whether it is OK to use it in my case. I do not think pulling the whole ASP.NET Core into my library should be needed, as I just need QueryStringBuilder, HeaderNames and maybe some other minor bits here and there. But the library is internal to our application, which I found to be a WebApplication and also use Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore. It just uses Microsoft.NET.Sdk in the project file (i.e. console project).

Comment: I haven't met this issue before, Thank your for sharing the solution with me, Learn a lot from this issue.

Comment: Would not mind a +1 on the question, @XinranShen. ;-)

Comment: We fixed these things neglected during the migration to ASP.NET Core 3.0, which was already the largest one I remember, and the new APIs of ASP.NET Core 6 became available. Specifically, we removed the package references and added FrameworkReference instead. Wrote up an answer to summarize the solution I already described in the comments, along with all the links.

Answer (score 1):

Between ASP.NET Core 2.2 and 3.0, the distribution model changed. Since .NET Core 3.0 and ASP.NET Core 3.0, the **individual packages of the framework itself are no longer published**, and the **[Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app) is supposed to be used** instead.

The shared framework is **referenced implicitly by the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK**.

For referencing the shared framework in class libraries and more generally **in projects using a different SDK, use FrameworkReference**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is recommended by the [guidance for ASP.NET Core use in class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework). When [deciding whether to preserve compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore#use-an-api-introduced-in-31) with ancient ASP.NET Core 2.2 and older or whether to use new APIs, there is another guide.

When migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 or older to a newer one, follow the guide for migration from 2.2 to 3.0: [remove the references to the old libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30#remove-obsolete-package-references) and use [FrameworkReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?#framework-reference) where appropriate.

While already using newer ASP.NET Core, take care not to add references to the NuGet packages of ASP.NET Core 2.2. **Strangely, the old packages are not marked as deprecated.**

More reading on FrameworkReference:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3612
- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-FrameworkReference-in-NuGet
- [What <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> is actually do in .net core 3+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64478618/2157640)

Closely related questions:

- [How to reference ASP.NET Core 6 types in .NET 6 library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70847263/2157640)
- [ASP.NET Core 3: How to reference 3.0.0 assemblies in custom libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58175530/2157640)